# "Split View" app on Android

Tags: android-layout

I am new to Android development. I like to develop application in "split view"(ipad has inbuilt framework). I did sample for "WVGA800" landscape mode, but for multiple screen not able to fix it. sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget32"
android:layout_width="395dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ff99ff99"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/widget31"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget31"
>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget31"
android:layout_width="166dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ff9999ff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The above one is sample layout. can any one suggest me how to fix "split view" for multiple screens.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, RelativeLayout is flat-out broken if you're trying to use attributes like "toRightOf" (you know, the *relative* ones). I'm not sure that Fragments are going to solve your problem, since they would replace your LinearLayouts but not the container, where the problem is.

You can do this with a horizontal LinearLayout containing two vertical LinearLayouts (or Fragments, if you prefer). All you need to do is change the layout_weight attributes of the two children reciprocally (increase one when you decrease the other) when the user drags the splitter bar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Fragments now in the API 11. There's also support for the API 4 or greater, but I'm not sure if all features are supported. Take a look:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

For API 4:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html